# Read data from SD

Tags: serial, sd-card, float

I have logged  some data in my sdcard/FAT32 (format).
I can read and display them on the serial monitor but additionally I want to use these data as float.

Here is my code:

```
       byte index = 0;

       Tfile = SD.open("DATALOG.TXT",FILE_READ); 

       while (Tfile.available()) {

         x[index++] = Tfile.read();
         x[index] = '\0'; // NULL terminate the array
       }
```

Printing the data using:

```
   Serial.print(fileContents);
```

I receive  the following float values that are correct:

```
   .63
   15.63
   16.60
   16.60
   16.60
   16.60
   etc
```

Now I want to work with values so i need to store them on a double index:

```
    double dtemp[320];
    for(index = 0, i=0; index < 320; index++, i++) {
       dtemp[i] =  fileContents[index];
       Serial.println(dtemp[i]); }
```

but i receive fault values:

```
      46.00
      54.00
      51.00
      13.00
      10.00
      49.00
      53.00
      etc
```

Any comment is welcomed !

Thank you in advance !

Comment: The "fault" values are the ASCII code...ok there is a solution reading the valid values(excluding the new line and carriage return) an putting them in an index 5x320, each line will be whole number and then I can store it in a float... but is there a faster way?

Answer (score 2):

You have to *parse* the character array in order to convert it to
floats. There is no fast way to do this: since the Arduino has no FPU,
*anything* involving floats is slow.

Unless you really have to, I would not recommend slurping the whole file
into RAM. You will save memory by parsing the file on the fly. This
should be as simple as calling the `parseFloat()` method of the `File`
object:

```c++
double dtemp[320];
int i;
for (i = 0; Tfile.avalable() && i < 320; i++) {
    dtemp[i] = Tfile.parseFloat();
    Serial.println(dtemp[i]);
}
if (i < 320)
    Serial.println("WARNING: Premature end of file.");
```

Comment: Be careful with `i` declaration, `byte` is too small tp hold a value as big as 320.

Comment: @jfpoilpret: Oops! My bad. Just fixed it, thanks.

Comment: using double or float, arduino (UNO in my case) stops responding and it doesn't print anything in the serial monitor. Using int, it parses the integer part of the number correctly....

Comment: This is very weird. The `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` functions are _extremely_ similar, and they both implement timeouts. Neither should hang your Uno. I suspect your error lies somewhere else in your code. Could you please update your question with a minimal – but _complete_ – sketch that reproduces the problem? Both the int version that works and the float version that does not please.